# When is a post deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

When is a post deleted, either by the system automatically or by moderators manually?

In particular, when a post is deleted by the system automatically, what is the criterion for taking the action? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overview of deletion is in the FAQ post 
[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Additionally, the criteria for automatic deletion are stated in the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

Some guidelines for deletion are on the [10K privilege page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and [20K privilege page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: Thanks. I can still access some recently deleted posts of mine. Will deleted posts be permanently removed and therefore never be accessible?

Comment: In addition, users with 10k rep or more can see all deleted questions and answers, as documented in the linked privilege pages.

Comment: soup, thanks. I tried to search my deleted posts on android.stackexchange.com, by android.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1, but it doesn't seem to show the deleted posts of mine. What does 'deleted%3A1' mean actually?